Prove that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ with respect to the uniform norm if and only if it converges uniformly to $f$.
Problem
Let $f$ and $f_1,f_2,\dots$ be continuous functions on $[a,b]$. Prove that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ with respect to the uniform norm if and only if it converges uniformly to $f$.

Definition$\quad$ The function $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}:C[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by the formula
\begin{align*}
    \|f\|_{\infty} = \sup\left\{|f(x)|:x\in[a,b]\right\}
\end{align*}
is a norm (the continuity of $f$ and the compactness of $[a,b]$ imply that $\|f\|_{\infty}$ is finite; this is important because the codomain of a norm is $\mathbb{R}$). This is norm is called the uniform norm on $C[a,b]$.

My Attempt
Let $\epsilon>0$. Suppose first that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$. This implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n(x)-f(x)\|_{\infty} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\{|f_n(x)-f(x)|:x\in[a,b]\}=0$. Then there is an integer $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $\sup\{|f_n(x)-f(x)|:x\in[a,b]\}<\epsilon$, and so $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. So $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$.
Conversely, suppose that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$. Then there is an integer $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq\epsilon$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ and so $\sup\{|f_n(x)-f(x)|:x\in[a,b]\}\leq\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\{|f_n(x)-f(x)|:x\in[a,b]\} = 0$, and thus $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$.
My Question
I am not sure whether my attempt is correct. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me check! Especially, in the second paragraph, I claimed that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\{|f_n(x)-f(x)|:x\in[a,b]\} = 0$. However, by the definition of a convergent sequence, we have to have strict inequality to conclude the limit exists (see below).
The following definition is taken from Baby Rudin:

Definition$\quad$ A sequence $\{p_n\}$ in a metric space $X$ is said to converge if there is a point $p$ in $X$ with the following property: For every $\epsilon>0$ there is an integer $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies that $d(p_n,p)<\epsilon$. In this case, we wrtie $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n=p$.


Note that $|f|\infty < \epsilon$ implies $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$. In the reverse direction, if $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$ then $|f|\infty \le \epsilon$ (not $<$!).

@copper.hat Thanks for your comment! Quick question: Does $|f(x)|\leq\epsilon$ for all $x$ imply $|f|_{\infty}\leq\epsilon$?

Your attempt is correct. Don't worry about the strict inequality in the definition. You can show that: For a sequence $(x_n)$ and an element $x$,

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, d(x_n, x) < \epsilon \ \forall n \ge N \Longleftrightarrow \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, d(x_n, x) \le \epsilon \ \forall n \ge N$


 $(\Longrightarrow)$ This is straightforward. As, $a < b$ implies $a \le b$


$(\Longleftarrow)$ Fix $\epsilon > 0$. There exists $N \in \mathbb{N}, d(x_n, x) \le \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} \ \forall n \ge N$. Thus, $d(x_n, x) < \epsilon \ \forall n \ge N$

